# Cannot receive UDP fragmented packets in C# appliaction

Tags: c#, visual-studio, udp

I have an embedded device that transmits UDP data back to a pc. I have developed a C# application that receives the packets and stores them in a buffer. The majority of the data received is less than the Ethernet MTU (1500 bytes but 1472 bytes payload). But some data is more than this so the board will send the data as fragmented. I can see using Wireshark that the packets are being sent OK from the board. But if I set a breakpoint in my C# code it never hits. Its as though the fragmented packet isn't getting through to the application. I am using Windows 10. Is there something I need to do in my C# program? Below is the code I am using to start the receive.

```
clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.dataStream, 0, this.dataStream.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epServer, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);
```

Comment: You have to combine the receive data together in the Receive Event.

Comment: Thanks  for your comment. Can you give me a reference showing how to do that? I am more of an embedded programmer so my C# experience is limited. Thanks

Comment: Best place to start is the msdn example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example).

Comment: What is the format of the received data?  Is it binary or ASCII?  Is there a byte count at beginning or a terminating character?  You need to be able to determine where the end of each record occurs so you know if it you get more than one record in each receive message or if records are in more than one receive message.  The example is really very simple and only shows the transport layer and doesn't handle application layer where messages may have multiple records or records come in multiple messages.

Comment: The data is binary. But I dont seem to even get anything in the C# program. The receive function never executes

Comment: If the board send less data than the MTU then the receive works fine. In wireshark I see two packets. One says IPV4 and the other is UDP. The first has the majority of the data and the second the remaining bytes. Everything looks fine in wireshark but the C# never gets the data

Comment: The example has a Receive Event (when connection is made)  2) ReceiveCallback when data is received.  Are you getting to either event (put break points).  On sniffer are you seeing UDP or TCP?  Is sniffer on same PC you are receiving data?  From cmd.exe >Netstat -A.  Check the status of the port number.  You said you are getting the short packets and not the fragmented packets.  Is that true?  Are you closing connection after each receive message?

Comment: Are you closing connection?  You would see a [FIN] in sniffer and the Netstat -A status would change.

Comment: I will have a look with netstat and see what it says. Using netstat I cant see any UDP connections, although Wireshark shows the packet

Comment: It is possible that you are seeing a continuation packet in the sniffer but getting all the data in one chunk in your code.  Check the byte count of the receive message in c# to see if chunks are being combined.  If you put break points is also could be different then code running without break points.  With break points you  could be receiving data in one chunk and without break points you could be receiving data in multiple chunks.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am really struggling to know what to do. I just tried with a code example I found that just sends some data then waits for data to be received. I dont get any data in the C# program. There must be something more to this as all the code I have tried doesnt work with fragmented packets.

Comment: Fragments are handled at the Ethernet Interface and you do not have to do anything different.  The issue could be due to a few different issues.  Would help if you posted code.  Can you receive multiple messages if they are all not fragmented?  I do not know if you can receive more than one message successfully.  What are you using do determine end or binary data?  Do not close connection if you get a message with zero bytes.  Are you seeing [FIN] in sniffer data?

Comment: Yes I can receive multiple UDP packets that are not fragmented. I am surprised its so difficult to do this. Would of thought the packet should be just received as normal.

Comment: You can getting one receive message with fragmented packets so I suspect the fragments are already combined.  Check the byte in c# count of the received message against the number of bytes in the sniffer data.  See if you are receiving in c# the fragments in one chunk.